# Duplicate Data Fetched using mysql JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have queried 5 tables using JOIN but i get duplicate data for every one record fetched i get 8 rows of the same data.
HERE IS MY CODE

```
          <?php
    include("dbconnection.php");
      $list = "SELECT user.user_id,user.empid,personal.fname,employment.position,employment.dep,educational.level,contact.phone_one,contact.phone_relation_one
       FROM user JOIN personal JOIN employment JOIN contact JOIN educational
          ON  (personal.empid_personal=user.empid = employment.empid_emp = contact.empid_contact)";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$list);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo    "<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>";
        echo    "<td>".$row['empid']."</td>";
        echo    "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
        echo     "<td>".$row['position']."</td>";
        echo     "<td>".$row['dep']."</td>";
        echo     "<td>".$row['level']."</td>";
        echo    "<td>".$row['phone_one']."</td>";
        echo    "<td>" .$row['phone_relation_one']."</td>";
        echo   '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del</a></td>';
        echo "</tr> ";

      }
       ?>
             </table>
```

Comment: You could toss a `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` ... but it'll slow it down.

Comment: THERE'S NO NEED TO YELL.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL should be more like...

```
  $list = "SELECT user.user_id,user.empid,personal.fname,employment.position,employment.dep,educational.level,contact.phone_one,contact.phone_relation_one
   FROM user 
   JOIN personal ON personal.empid_personal=user.empid
   JOIN employment ON  user.empid = employment.empid_emp
   JOIN contact ON user.empid = contact.empid_contact
   JOIN educational ON ?????";
```

This links each joined table to the main table (in this case anyway).

There should also be some sort of link for the `educational` table, but you don't list this.  This is also probably where duplicates can come in, linking to a table without any conditions on how to match the data, also known as a CROSS JOIN.